# AngularJS displaying data from an array

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that returns an array from my django view, i am trying to display each object in a different line in my html but it just returns json.

**my controller.js**

```
mainApp.controller('hsController', function($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout, $location) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.init = function() {
        console.log("angular loaded!")
    }

    $scope.data.form = {
        hs_search: "",

        result: {},
    };
    $scope.data.formStyle = {
        hs_search: ""
    };
    
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        //console.log($scope.data.form)
        var error = 0;
        if(!$scope.data.form.hs_search) {
            $scope.data.formStyle.hs_search = "is_invalid";
            error++;
        } else {
            $scope.data.formStyle.hs_search = "";
        }
        if(error==0) {
            var jsonCall = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'/theapp/hs-code-search',
                data: $scope.data.form,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            });
            jsonCall.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data.status==1) {
                    $scope.data.form.result = data.data
                    console.log($scope.data.form.result)
                }
            });
            jsonCall.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data.status==0) {
                    $.growl.error({ message: data.error});
                }
            });
            console.log($scope.data.form)
        } else {
            $.growl.error({ message: "Please fill the form correctly!"});
        }
    }
});
```

**my html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 mx-auto">
        <h3>Search Result For </h3>
                                
        <div ng-repeat="chapter_code in data.form.result">
            {[{chapter_code}]}
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="chapter_desc in data.form.result">
            {[{chapter_desc}]}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result that am getting**
[image]

What i wanted instead is just the value of each object shown.

Comment: Please add some sample data and verify that it works by using a runnable snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the JSON to an Object using JSON.parse() and then you can use ng-repeat

myController.js

```
if(data.status==1) {
                $scope.data.form.result = JSON.parse(data.data);
                console.log($scope.data.form.result);
                // Console shall return an Object
            }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 mx-auto">
    <h3>Search Result For </h3>
                            
    <div ng-repeat="chapterCode in data.form.result.chapter_code">
        {{chapterCode}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="chapterDesc in data.form.result.chapter_desc">
        {{chapterDesc}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```